# Set ul's width to the widest child's width

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have got a small problem of displaying a ul. I am a CSS beginner.

I want the width of my `ul` to be equal to the widest `listitem` it contains.

I have used the HTML as follows:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <ul id="sidebarSelector">
        <li><a href="#">Social Spot</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="selectedSidebarItem">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Latest</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
#sidebar
{
    float:left;
    width:20%;
}

#sidebar > ul#sidebarSelector
{
    margin-top:100px;

    list-style:none;
    text-align:right;
    /*overflow:auto;*/
}

#sidebar > ul#sidebarSelector > li > a
{
    display:block;
    padding:5px 10px;
    font-family: "Open Sans Bold", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:500;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color:#000000;
}

.selectedSidebarItem
{
    background-color:#0094ff;
    font-weight:700;
    border-radius: 3px; /*for rounded edges*/
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #0094ff; /*for glowing*/
}
```

I have tried the below mentioned jQuery function but I was unsuccessful.

```
$.fn.textWidth = function(text, font) {
    if (!$.fn.textWidth.fakeEl) $.fn.textWidth.fakeEl = $('<span>').appendTo(document.body);
    var htmlText = text || this.val() || this.text();
    htmlText = $.fn.textWidth.fakeEl.text(htmlText).html(); //encode to Html
    htmlText = htmlText.replace(/\s/g, "&nbsp;"); //replace trailing and leading spaces
    $.fn.textWidth.fakeEl.html(htmlText).css('font', font || this.css('font'));
    return $.fn.textWidth.fakeEl.width();
};

var maxWidth = 0;
  $('a').each(function(i){
    if($(this).textWidth($(this).text, $(this).css('font')) > maxWidth)
      maxWidth = $(this).textWidth($(this).text, $(this).css('font'));
  });

$('#sidebarSelector').width(maxWidth);
```

Using above Html and css I got output as shown in image below:

[image]

Required output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know your entire structure, but removing `width: 20%` from `#sidebar` will get the result you want without JavaScript code, but your sidebar will get the value of the bigger text in your unordered list:

```css
#sidebar {
  float: left;
  /*width: 20%;*/
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thiagobraga/rwLh20gp/)

### Edit

Just add a `float: left` and `padding-left: 0` to your `ul` element. The `padding-left` is to cancel the space added by agent (Chrome added a space in the left of the `ul` in my JSFiddle):

```css
#sidebar {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc; /* Only to visualize the solution */
}

#sidebar > ul#sidebarSelector {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 0;
  /* ...and the rest of your code */
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thiagobraga/rwLh20gp/2)

Comment: Thanks. That works well. But if I remove width:20% then how can I get the layout as header, sidebar and working-area?

Comment: Thank you very much. That works fine even with float: right which I want.

Answer (score 2):

you have to give a width to ul or it will adjust to your sidebar's width, which is 20%

Try this code:

```
#sidebar {
    float:left;

}
ul#sidebarSelector {
    margin-top:100px;
    width:auto;
    max-width:125px;
    list-style:none;
    text-align:right;
    /*overflow:auto;*/
}
#sidebarSelector li {
    width:auto;
}
#sidebarSelector li a {
    display:block;
    padding:5px 10px;
    font-family:"Open Sans Bold", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:500;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color:#000000;
}
.selectedSidebarItem {
    background-color:#0094ff;
    font-weight:700;
    border-radius: 3px;
    /*for rounded edges*/
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #0094ff;
    /*for glowing*/
}
```

[see fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/019p395m/)

Note: the max-width of 125px is for illustrative purposes, you may need a different one, specially with web-fonts, but you'll get the idea

Comment: You are absolutely right, that I should give width to ul. But my problem is that I generate items dynamically using jquery. So if item's name is greater than the specified width, then half of the item will come to next line.

Comment: if you remove the max-width, it will work the same, only that your sidebar will vary in width (same as removing the sidebar width alone). While this is what you may want, I just added styling (and you should as well) to avoid a 100% width sidebar. But of course, it goes on your taste and your needs, I have noticed that nobody cared about the look of the sidebar at all, so maybe that's what you need, who knows. I worked based in your code and look, hence no random stuff

Answer (score 0):

You can get the width of the widest element and apply it to all other elements.

```
var maxWidth = 0;
$("a").each(function(){
   if($(this).width() > maxWidth){
     maxWidth = $(this).width();
   }
});

$("a").width(maxWidth);
```

And remove the `width: 20%` from your `#sidebar`.

#### [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j7aos0pn/1/)

**EDIT**: While this answers your specific question, it looks like you don't really need to use any JS at all, as noted in @thiagobraga's answer.

Comment: that does the same thing that i got.

Comment: Just updated, also need to remove the width styling from your `#sidebar`.

Answer (score 0):

I've a `CSS` solution for your problem. Use `white-space: nowrap;` in your `css` and get the expected result.

Here is a fiddle **[link](http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/er6pch2n/1/)**.

Comment: You also removed the width styling FYI, you should mention that.

Comment: Yes I did but I expect the OP has put this style to set width of the sidebar based on his layout.